# Xcode error when archiving iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am trying to archive an iOS app but it keeps on giving me errors. The app runs smoothly when played in an iOS device. My Xcode project is generated from Unity 4.6.7, and I'm trying to build it on Xcode 6.0. The iOS deployment target is 8.0.

Here are the errors I encountered:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "__storeKitDisplayStoreWithProductId", referenced from:
>         _StoreKitBinding__storeKitDisplayStoreWithProductId_m1449 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _StoreKitBinding__storeKitDisplayStoreWithProductId_m1449_MethodInfo, _StoreKitBinding__storeKitDisplayStoreWithProductId_m1449 )
>     "__storeKitRestoreCompletedTransactions", referenced from:
>         _StoreKitBinding__storeKitRestoreCompletedTransactions_m1445 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_1.o
>         _StoreKitBinding_restoreCompletedTransactions_m1446 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _StoreKitBinding__storeKitRestoreCompletedTransactions_m1445,

Fix I made so far:

I removed StoreKit.framework and manually readded it to Frameworks by dragging and dropping. Also, I set the architecture to this:

Standard architectures(armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

What else am i possibly missing?

Your response will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you select IL2CPP in `Scripting Backend` option? File -> Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Other Settings (in IOS) -> Configuration (in Unity)

Comment: Yes. It's the current setting of Scripting Backend.

Comment: did you get solution? how fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the problem is here, however it looks like the problem is that you are using an older version of Xcode. Update to the latest version (7.2 at the time of writing). Also I recommend increasing your iOS deployment target to 9.0, and updating Unity to the latest version. I had a similar problem like this, which was fixed by changing the deployment target to the latest. I haven't used Unity in a while, but I suspect that there could be an error in the Unity build. I highly encourage you contact Apple, or Unity on this issue.

Comment: There were no errors in Unity build, but when already archiving in Xcode, it gives me the errors above. Also, i changed the deployment target to a higher version(8.1) and Xcode version to 7.1 but i still get the same errors. ://

Comment: Try updating Xcode to 7.2, iOS to 9.2, and deployment target to 9.2.

Comment: I tried using Xcode 6.1, DP Target 8.1, and iOS 8.1 because the latest target iOS version in my Unity 4.6.7 is 8.1. I also tried Xcode 6.2 and 7.1, but i get the same errors.

Comment: This is not the latest version. Update to the latest version (Xcode to 7.2, iOS to 9.2, and deployment target to 9.2 at the time of writing), unless your devices are unable to support these. If you update to the latest version and it still doesn't work, then I am sorry to say that I cannot help you.